# Starting Domain Registration Service

Tags: domain-registrar, registration, domains

I have been working as a web developer for long time. I have regular request from clients for web hosting and domain registration whose site i make.

I have been asking for other frens for it. And they have been doing it for $15/year per domain registration.

I am thinking to start the registration by self.

So what are the things to do for being able to register domain names in cheaper rates less than $15/year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Google search for "register domain", or just [get a decent web host](http://www.dreamhost.com/domains.html) that doesn't rip you off on domain registration.

Most domain registrars only charge about $9-10 a year to register a .com/.net/.org domain. And even web hosts that aren't registrars usually offer these end-user prices. There's no reason to pay more than $10 per year for a standard domain.

Though it sounds like you just want to take the place of those shady registrars that charge >$10/year for domains.

A domain registration service is about as useful as an AdWords account setup service. Anyone who can read and has access to the internet can register their own domain in less than 5 minutes. It's as easy as creating an e-mail account. It would actually take more time, be more risky, and be more of a pain to go through a third party.

Anyone buying a website for the first time needs to sign up for hosting anyways. And pretty much all web hosts walk you through the process of registering your first domain. Why a separate "domain registration service" is needed is beyond me. That's just one more delay and one more person to hand your credit card information to.

If, say, you sign up with DreamHost for shared hosting, you can just type in a domain name, check availability, and register it with a single mouse click. You won't have an extra account to worry about or have to go in and change DNS records to point to your web host.

Comment: +1 ... and, as a service to the reader, an important note from someone who has worked in the domain registration and hosting industry: Unless you go **big** (very, very big) you will most likely be **losing** money as a domain reseller. Support overhead adds up quickly.

Comment: I disagree with your last few paragraphs. Registering your domain with a company like GoDaddy versus your web host gives you much more flexibility and control. From past experience, it is a big pain when you need to switch hosts to switch the domain out of their possession. Oftentimes they will even register it under their own information, which further complicates it. But when you register with a third party, YOU are the one that retains control over everything. Taking an extra 30 seconds to enter DNS information seems well worth it to me. You will probably save a few bucks too.

Comment: @James Skidmore: GoDaddy is also a webhost... And I've never had any problems moving domains between major registrars, though I don't see why you would even need to. If you register separately from your hosting company, then you need to keep track of 2 accounts. If you register with your web host and later switch hosting, then you need to keep track of 2 accounts. Also, how is it cheaper to pay an extra $9/year for a domain than to use the free domain you get with most web hosts?

Comment: It sounds to me like you've had some bad experiences with some poor web hosts. That's a problem you need to look out for regardless of whether you register your domain separately. You should not be using a hosting company that isn't able to perform simple tasks like domain transfers (this is something that web hosts have to do all the time). You also shouldn't use a hosting company that doesn't have a cPanel-type interface that lets you easily manage your domains. You don't need separate hosting and registration companies.